# Issue with aws profiles when building AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-ami, packer

I have an issue building AMIs using AWS profiles with packer. The AWS profile is not being identified by packer config file, its using default credentials.

.aws/config

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-east-2

[profile test]
output = json
region = us-east-2

[profile test-dev]
output = json
region = us-east-2
```

.aws/credentials(not real keys)

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id =
aws_secret_access_key =

[test]
aws_access_key_id = 1fsfsfsd9898sf
aws_secret_access_key = 123456789fsdfsf8fs080sd8

[test-dev]
aws_access_key_id = fdafda8f0s80d8f0
aws_secret_access_key = fdsflsjlfjsl908809830sfjsdjl
```

config.json

```
  {
    "variables": {
            "aws_access_key": "",
            "aws_secret_key": "",
            "aws_profile": "test-dev"
    },


    "builders": [{
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
        "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
        "region": "us-east-2",
        "profile": "{{user `profile`}}",
        "source_ami": "ami-336b4456",
        "instance_type": "t2.micro",
        "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
        "ami_name": "packer-example {{timestamp}}"
    }],

    "provisioners": [{
          "type": "shell",
          "execute_command": "sudo -S bash '{{.Path}}'",
          "script": "provision1.sh"
    }]`
```

**Its taking the values of test instead of test-dev**

Comment: I have tried using "aws_default_profile" and "profile" in variables section, but no luck!

Comment: Did you try using AWS_PROFILE as seen [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/2471#issuecomment-123459374)

Answer (score 1):

Your template reads:

```
"profile": "{{user `profile`}}"
```

But should reference the user var with:

```
"profile": "{{user `aws_profile`}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to specify the profile in the template file, you can run the build command like:

```
AWS_PROFILE=yourprofile packer build template.json
```

where `yourprofile` is the name of the AWS profile that you want to use.